# MailCore2 Search Expression with more than two parameters?

Tags: mailcore2

How can I search mailcore2 with more than two expressions?

My example below includes exprSinceLastTime as well as exprFrom and exprSubject. But, searchAdd only has room for two parameters.

How can I add additional search expressions such as exprSinceLastTime?

```
 NSTimeInterval oneHour = 3600;
 NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:oneHour];
 MCOIMAPSearchExpression * exprSinceLastTime = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchSinceReceivedDate:now];


MCOIMAPSearchExpression * exprFrom = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchFrom: @"apple"];
MCOIMAPSearchExpression * exprSubject = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchSubject: @"cloudkit"];
MCOIMAPSearchExpression * expr = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchAnd: exprFrom other: exprSubject];

MCOIMAPSearchOperation* searchOperation = [session searchExpressionOperationWithFolder: folder expression: expr];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post the answer below. It was very simple. I had to sleep on the question to think of the obvious answer :-)

```
 NSTimeInterval oneHour = 3600; // magic number! 60 seconds
 NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:oneHour];
 MCOIMAPSearchExpression * exprSinceLastTime = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchSinceReceivedDate:now];


MCOIMAPSearchExpression* exprFrom = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchFrom: @"youtube"];
MCOIMAPSearchExpression* exprSubject = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchSubject: @"video"];
MCOIMAPSearchExpression* expr = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchAnd: exprFrom other: exprSubject];
MCOIMAPSearchExpression* expr2 = [MCOIMAPSearchExpression searchAnd: exprSinceLastTime other: expr];

MCOIMAPSearchOperation* searchOperation = [session searchExpressionOperationWithFolder: folder expression: expr2];
```